# How to restrict access to content to anonymous user in Plone-4?

Tags: content-management-system, plone, plone-4.x

On a Plone 4.3.18 install, how can I restrict access to some published content to only authenticated users?

I need to create a section in the my site which content is visible only to authenticated users, or a specific group of users, but I'm not finding the way to do it in the site configurations.

Comment: If you want to do this to some content only, use the Sharing feature https://docs.plone.org/working-with-content/collaboration-and-workflow/collaboration-through-sharing.html Usually it's best to post questions to our forum https://community.plone.org/ where more people will see them

Comment: What I was missing where to enable the Workflow component (CMFPlacefulWorkflow), and change the site workflow configuration to "Intranet/Extranet". With it I could "publish internally" and "publish externally" the content. I'll write this better as an answer if someone else needs this and asks me to.